# Fixing my crash using Crashlytics error logs

Tags: swift, logging, crash, report, crashlytics

I've got an error log from Crashlytics that reads as following:

```
Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x1d003d5a0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  (App Name)            0x100710fa4 specialized ViewController.(getHistoricalData(url : String, currency : String) -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift:1324)
1  (App Name)             0x1007029f8 ViewController.(getHistoricalData(url : String, currency : String) -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift)
2  (App Name)             0x100712178 partial apply for ViewController.(getHistoricalData(url : String, currency : String) -> ()).(closure #1) (ViewController.swift)
3  (App Name)             0x1006fd448 @callee_owned (@owned Data?, @owned URLResponse?, @owned Error?) -> ()NSData?NSData (ViewController.swift)
4  CFNetwork                      0x181fd1d68 __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
5  CFNetwork                      0x181fea6bc __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 152
6  Foundation                     0x18241dba0 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
7  Foundation                     0x18235d894 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
8  Foundation                     0x18234d4c4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 848
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1813c6a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1814029c4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 280
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1813c6a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x1814029c4 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 280
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x181402878 dispatch_block_perform$VARIANT$armv81 + 104
14 Foundation                     0x18241f878 __NSOQSchedule_f + 376
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1813c6a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x181403640 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 420
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x181401fe8 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 + 596
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1814082a4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 568
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x181408008 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18166f06c _pthread_wqthread + 1268
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18166eb6c start_wqthread + 4
```

Where `(App Name)` corresponds to my app's name. To my understanding the error is happening at line 1324 of ViewController.swift, in the function `getHistoricalData(url : String, currency : String)`.
That functions is as follows:

```
func getHistoricalData(url: String, currency: String){
        var Currenturl = NSURL(string: url)


        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() {

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (Currenturl as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                if let jsonObj = jsonObj  {


                  // do some stuff
                }
            }).resume()

        }
    }
```

Line 1324 corresponds to `let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary`

I have already tried a few different methods of unwrapping `jsonObj` to try and stop this crash. Originally I had something like `if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {` but same issue was occurring.

Is it to do with the way I am unwrapping? Any ideas/pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the error is in `let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary`, there are two plain error causes:

- The cast to `NSDictionary` fails for whatever reason
- Force unwrapping `data` fails.

Don't force-unwrap server-received data using `!`, it may be nil. Use the following code instead:

```
guard let data = data, let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary else { // Handle error here }
```

Comment: You sir, are a fine gentlemen. This has worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your assistance.